# Passing List<T> by reference to a method accepting ref ICollection<T>

Tags: c#, pass-by-reference, c#-7.0

I've noticed that a `List<T>` cannot be passed to methods such as:

- `Foo<T>(ref ICollection<T> bar)`
- `Foo<T>(out ICollection<T> bar)`

Taking into account that, on the other side, `Foo<T>(ICollection<T> bar)` does accept a `List<T>` as argument, could anyone please explain the described behavior to me?

Complete example:

```
public class AuxClass { }

public class Test
{
    private void NonRefFoo<T>(ICollection<T> intCollection) {; }
    private void RefFoo<T>(ref ICollection<T> intCollection) {; }
    private void OutFoo<T>(out ICollection<T> intCollection) { intCollection = null; }

    public void Foo()
    {
        {
            List<int> list = new List<int>() { 0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13 };
            List<AuxClass> classList = new List<AuxClass>() { new AuxClass() };

            NonRefFoo<int>(list);
            RefFoo<int>(ref list);                                  // Invalid
            OutFoo<AuxClass>(out List<int> outListInt);             // Invalid

            NonRefFoo<AuxClass>(classList);
            RefFoo<AuxClass>(ref classList);                        // Invalid
            OutFoo<AuxClass>(out List<AuxClass> outListClass);      // Invalid
        }

        {
            ICollection<int> collection = new List<int>() { 0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13 };
            ICollection<AuxClass> classCollection = new List<AuxClass>() { new AuxClass() };

            NonRefFoo<int>(collection);
            OutFoo<int>(out ICollection<int> outCollectionInt);
            RefFoo<int>(ref collection);

            NonRefFoo<AuxClass>(classCollection);
            RefFoo<AuxClass>(ref classCollection);
            OutFoo<AuxClass>(out ICollection<AuxClass> outCollectionClass);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `ref` allows you to assign something else to the variable alias, something that is an `ICollection<T>`. Problem: *any* old `ICollection<T>` could not be assigned to a `List<T>` variable.

Comment: See also: [Why can’t I pass a reference to a derived class to a function that takes a reference to a base class by reference?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20090812-00/?p=17133)

Comment: Thanks!
I've just found this related article too:
[Why do ref and out parameters not allow type variation?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/09/21/why-do-ref-and-out-parameters-not-allow-type-variation/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the ref there is a possibility (and with the out a certainty) that you will assign a new object to property you pass in. In this case anything of type `ICollection<T>`. If you pass in an object of type `List<T>` you might end up assigning an object of a unrelated type that implements `ICollection<T>`. The c# type system doesn't allow that and the compiler knows this and so stops you doing it