# How to replace an element in a Collection

Tags: c#, .net, collections

The thing I wanna do would appear really simple - I want to find an element in an `ICollection<T>` that satisfies a given predicate and replace it with another. In C++ I would write this like:

```
for(auto &element : collection) {

    if(predicate(elem)) {
        element = newElement;
    }
}
```

Grab the element by reference and reassign it. However doing

```
foreach(ref var element in collection)
```

in C# fails to compile, and I'm unsure if it'd even do what I want if it did compile. How do I access the physical reference within a collection to modify it?

My method signature if it helps:

```
public static void ReplaceReference<T>(
    ICollection<T> collection, 
    T newReference, 
    Func<T, bool> predicate)
```

EDIT:

Since it appears unclear, I cannot just take the `ICollection<T>` and change it to something else. I'm getting an `ICollection` - that's all I know and I can't change that. No matter how much I'd love this to be an `IList`, or `IEasilyReplacable` I can't influence that.

Comment: I removed the C++ as this doesn't have anything to do with writing C++ code

Comment: You cannot modify the reference itself when you are iterating over a collection using `foreach`. You can, however, modify members of the referenced item.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So I bashed my head against the wall and came up with a really simple solution for the particular replace problem, which is to find, remove and then add.

```
var existing = collection.FirstOrDefault(predicate);

if (existing != null)
{
    collection.Remove(existing);    
    collection.Add(newReference);
}
```

However, I see it as rather a workaround to my `foreach` issue, and have thus posted this question as a follow-up: [Grab element from a Collection by reference in a foreach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52006182/grab-element-from-a-collection-by-reference-in-a-foreach)

EDIT:

For Daniel A. White's comment:

Handling only the first one was what I intended to do, but it can be easily changed to replace-all:

```
var existing = collection.Where(predicate);

foreach(var element in existing)
{
    collection.Remove(element);
}

for(int i = 0; i < existing.Count); ++i)
{
    collection.Add(newReference);
}
```

As for ordering - `ICollection` is not necessarily ordered. So the way for fixing that would be creating a new method with a less general signature

```
static void ReplaceReference<T>(
    IList<T> list, 
    T newReference, 
    Func<T, bool> predicate)
```

that would use the indexer to replace the values

```
for(int i = 0; i < list.Count; ++i)
{
    if(predicate(list[i]))
    {
        list[i] = newReference;
        // break here if replace-one variant.
    }
}
```

And now in the main method we check if our collection is an IList, therefore ordered, and pass it to the ordered version:

```
if(collection is IList<T> list)
{
    ReplaceReference(list, newReference, predicate);
    return;
}
```

===========================================================================

Sidenote: of course there is also the dumbo approach:

```
var newCollection = new List<T>();

foreach(var element in collection)
{
    newList.Add(predicate(element) ? newReference : element);
}

collection.Clear();

foreach(var newElement in newCollection)
{
    collection.Add(newElement);
}
```

but it's highly inefficient.

Comment: this only accounts for the first one. plus it will put more than likely at the end of the collection.

Comment: Edited with solutions to these issues.

Answer (score 2):

- `ICollection<T>` wouldn't be the best for this scenario. `IList<T>` allows you to assign with the indexer.
- Another option would be to create a new collection as you iterate.
- You could also write some sort of wrapper that is the actual reference in the collection and holds the value:

```
ICollection<Wrapper<T>> collection = ...;

foreach(var wrapper in collection)
{
    wrapper.Value = newValue;
}
```

Comment: or `.Remove(oldValue)` and `.Add(newValue)` (with `ICollection<T>`)

Comment: @RandRandom you shouldn't modify a collection while its enumerating. also most collections will put an `.Add` at the end.

Comment: `you shouldn't modify a collection while its enumerating` - thats also true for you first point

Comment: @RandRandom it only changes a value, not the structure of the collection.

Comment: it will still break with enumeration changed exception if you only do that

Comment: @RandRandom it wont break the iteration if accessed by index

Comment: Since when are we talking about a for loop? here the foreach version https://dotnetfiddle.net/EYUgMD

Comment: @RandRandom sure you can't change it. an indexer would require (mostly) a `for` loop.

Comment: well atleast someone liked my Remove/Add solution :D

Comment: This doesn't fit my method signature, I edited the question to clearly state you can't just change the collection's type.

Answer (score 2):

As per my understanding you want to replace specific item in collection based on given predicate, I tried below code and it is works fine for me.

I've created a list of string with 4 items and i asked my generic method to search for string with value "Name 1" if it is true it should change it to value "Name 5".

I've tested it using console application so you can test it by creating forloop that show values of list using Console.WriteLine();

```
    public void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<string> list = new List<string>();
        list.Add("Name 1");
        list.Add("Name 2");
        list.Add("Name 3");
        list.Add("Name 4");

        Func<string, bool> logicFunc = (listItemValue) => listItemValue == "Name 1";
        ReplaceReference(list, "Name 5", logicFunc);
    }

    public static void ReplaceReference<T>(ICollection<T> collection, T newReference, Func<T, bool> predicate)
    {
        var typeName = typeof(T).Name;
        var newCollection = collection.ToList();
        for (int i = 0; i < newCollection.Count; i++)
        {
            if (predicate(newCollection[i]))
            {
                newCollection[i] = newReference;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, but no:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/C3cvUD
I want to change the actual collection, not create a copy with the element replaced.

Comment: You can then return collection<T> if you need to change the actual collection?
https://dotnetfiddle.net/4szXan

Comment: I think compiler will not allow to change the actual collection using ref the only way from my perspective is to return new collection with replaced values .. please see the answer available here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48351097/passing-listt-by-reference-to-a-method-accepting-ref-icollectiont