# Grab element from a Collection by reference in a foreach

Tags: c#, .net

This is a followup to this question:
[How to replace an element in a Collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52005747/how-to-replace-an-element-in-a-collection/52005970#52005970)

There I found a workaround for the particular issue of *replacing* something in a collection. However, that doesn't make it clear to me whether C# has the ability to express the same as, for example, the C++ foreach loop:

```
for(auto &element : collection) {
    // Yay, element is an actual reference to the object physically in the collection!
}
```

So I wanted modify the question to a general case: let's say I have an external method that takes an object of type `T` per reference:

```
void Foo<T>(ref T obj);
```

It's irrelevant what exactly this method does.

So I'd want to grab every element by the actual collection's reference and throw it into this method.

```
void ApplyFoo<T>(ICollection<T> collection)
{
    // Iterate over every element and pass it to Foo as a reference.
}
```

Is there a simple way to do this in C#? Maybe some syntactic sugar I don't know about?

If there is not is there any justification? Seems like this is actually limiting the expressive power of the language.

Comment: If `T` is a _reference_ type (not a _value_ type like a `struct`), then you always handle it by reference. If it's a value type, you never access the element physically in the collection, but always a copy of the value.

Comment: Technically speaking it's handled by value either way - for reference types it _copies the reference_. So if you do `foreach(var element in collection) element = null` you just did nothing.

Comment: And you still require that the reference that got passed into `Foo` can be set `obj = new T();` and this change will reflect into the list?

Comment: enjoy this reading : https://www.amazon.com/CLR-via-4th-Developer-Reference/dp/0735667454

Comment: How is this question a duplicate? I even linked the original, which is already solved with a workaround. It's clearly a more general question, and even if the answer is a simple "No", it's not a duplicate.

Answer (score -1):

At present there is no way to do that with the language or the framework APIs. As I mentioned in my other answer, you will have to have a wrapper reference type that holds the value and allows you to change it.